# Converting special HTML characters back into their original strings

Tags: php, html, htmlspecialchars

I'm building a small parser that scrapes web pages and logs the data on them. One of the things to log is the post title of forums. I'm using a XML parser to look through the DOM and get this information, and I'm storing it like this:

```
// Strip out the post's title
$title = $page->find('a[rel=bookmark]', 0);
$title = htmlspecialchars_decode(html_entity_decode(trim($title->plaintext)));
```

This works for the most part, but some posts have certain special HTML character codes like `&#8211;` which is dash (`-`). How would I go about converting these special character codes back into their original strings?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm surprised `htmlspecialchars_decode()` doesn't do this...

Comment: Never mind: per the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php): The converted entities are: `&amp;`, `&quot;` (when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set), `&#039;` (when ENT_QUOTES is set), `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: Would [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) work for you here?

Comment: urldecode is for URL not HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php). Here's a quick example.

```
$string = "hyphenated&#8211words";

$new = html_entity_decode($string);

echo $new;
```

You should see...

```
hyphenated–words
```

Comment: I already tried `html_entitity_decode`, it's in the code in my post. `$title = html_entity_decode(trim($title->plaintext));` still returns the post title with `&#8211;` instead of `-`.

Comment: Well this is the function, and I can't replicate your problem. What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) is your friend:

```
html_entity_decode(trim($title->plaintext), ENT_XHTML, YOUR_ENCODING);
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
<?php
 function clean_up($str){
 $str = stripslashes($str);
 $str = strtr($str, get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES));
 $str = str_replace( array("\x82", "\x84", "\x85", "\x91", "\x92", "\x93", "\x94", "\x95", "\x96",  "\x97"), array("&#8218;", "&#8222;", "&#8230;", "&#8216;", "&#8217;", "&#8220;", "&#8221;", "&#8226;", "&#8211;", "&#8212;"),$str);
return $str;
}
?>
```